# Most frequent text based on criteria from another column and ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, windows, excel-formula

I have below data where I need to get the most frequent text in column A based on column B,

***Data Set:***

[image]

I used the below code but it returns `#N/A` as I think it's possibly due to empty cells

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,MODE(IF($B$1:$B$11=3, MATCH($A$1:$A$11,$A$1:$A$11,0))))
```

Expected Result: "RED"

How to get the most frequent text ignoring blank cells and based on another column value?

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: I'm using 16.0.14026.20294 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another `IF()` to check and ignore blank cells.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MODE(IF($B$1:$B$10=3, IF(A1:A10<>"",MATCH($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10,0),""))))
```

You may need array entry with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` for non 365 version of excel.

With `Excel365` can use

```
=@SORTBY(A1:A10,COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10),-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer but it seems little lengthy..

[image: Ans..]